# SharePoint 2016 May 2017 CU update

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, cumulative-update

I am installing SharePoint 2016 with latest CU May 2017.
Do I have to install first Feature Pack 1 November 2016 CU and then install May 2017 CU OR only installing May 2017 CU will be enough (means May 2017 CU contains Nov 2016 CU)?

Comment: Did you get your answer? Looking at the questions you have asked before, I don't see you getting back to the answers whether they have been helpful to you. Have you seen the Help Center article for [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I wholeheartedly suggest you to go through this article.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to install November 2016 CU before installing May 2017 CU, as May 2017 CU includes the Feature Pack 1.

> This CU also includes Feature Pack 1 which was released with November 2016 CU.

Source: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2017/05/09/may-2017-cu-for-sharepoint-server-2016-is-available-for-download/

Answer (score 2):

May 2017 CU includes the Feature Pack 1 in it, simply install the May CU 2017.

Two things, you need to understand.

- You have to Install both patches [" SharePoint Server 2016 (language independent)"](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55210) & ["SharePoint Server 2016 (language dependent fixes)"](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55196) from May CU 2017. Order of installation does not matter, but you have to install the both packages.
- Run the config wizard after installation of both patches on all servers in the farm.